# WP - How to check capabilities inside a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to check if a user have capabilities to do something in the initialization of a plugin.
I tried with current_user_can() function, and WP_User class, but dont work in these scope.

The question is: I need to check if a user have capabilities in wp-admin, to let he see a specific menu or just to load the content of the plugin.
But how? Both methods above generates a php error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hook your function to run after plugins have loaded

```
function my_special_function() {
  if ( current_user_can( 'do_whatever' ) )
  // do your thing
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_special_function' );
```

Source: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23861